# How do I handle async functions in a loop?

Tags: swift

I'm looping through a table's rows, for each of them I'm doing a couple of async calls like fetching data from API, copying files, running shell script... How do I wait for the result until going to the next one.

Also I'm new to Swift, not sure if this is the best way to handle a group of async tasks. Should I use concurrency in this case ?

```
tableView.selectedRowIndexes.forEach { row in
     myData.fetch(url: urlList[row]) { res in
        self.anotherAsyncCall(res) { data in
            //continue to deal with next row now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the result of first call is not related to result of another call you can always make use of available concurrent APIs. Of top of my head I can think of utilizing 1. `NSOperation`. You can create multiple operations and add them to a queue. Based on availability of system resources multiple operations would get picked up by queue. 2. `DispatchGroup` Much simpler way to achieve the same, if you are not looking for granular control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this sequentially, the easiest way is to perform your tasks recursively, actually invoking the next task in the completion handler of the prior one:

```
processNext(in: tableView.selectedRowIndexes) {
    // do something when they're all done
}
```

Where:

```
func processNext(in rows: [Int], completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard let row = rows.first else {
        completion()
        return
    }

    myData.fetch(url: urlList[row]) { res in
        self.anotherAsyncCall(res) { data in
            //continue to deal with next row now

            self.processNext(in: Array(rows.dropFirst()), completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

But I agree with GoodSp33d that the other approach is to wrap this asynchronous process in a custom, asynchronous, `Operation` subclass.

---

But this begs the question why you want to do these sequentially. You will pay a significant performance penalty because of the inherent network latency for each request. So the alternative is to let them run concurrently, and use dispatch group to know when they're done:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

tableView.selectedRowIndexes.forEach { row in
    group.enter()
    myData.fetch(url: urlList[row]) { res in
        self.anotherAsyncCall(res) { data in
            //continue to deal with next row now
            group.leave()
        }
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // do something when they're all done
}
```

Whether you can run these concurrently (or to what degree) is a function of what you're doing inside various asynchronous methods. But I would suggest you think hard about making this work concurrently, as the performance is likely to be much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some promise library, just use the `all` function.

[Here](https://github.com/malcommac/Hydra#all) is some Document about promise.all()

And PromiseKit use `when` instead,
 you can read about the [faq](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#where-is-all) and the [tutorial about when](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md#waiting-on-multiple-promises-whatever-their-result) for more information.

If you want to do that without any promise library, here is the pseudocode:

```
var results = []
rows.forEach {row in
    fetch(row) {res in
        results.push(res)
        if(results.length == rows.length) {
            // do something using the results here
        }
    }
}
```